# UICollectionView inside of UICollectionView does not scroll

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController with a A UICollectionView inside it.
Each cell of the A UICollectionView is a B UICollectionView.

A UICollectionView has a vertical scroll.
B UICollectionView has a horizontal scroll.

For some reason, B UICollectionView does not scroll. What can be the reason? And how can this be fixed?

Here is how I register for inner cells (maybe I do it wrong):

```
class AUICollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView! //{ didSet { collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "BUICollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BUICollectionViewCell") } } (this didn't work either)

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "BUICollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BUICollectionViewCell")
    }
...
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show a demo ?

Comment: It delayed, not canceled. Try hold your finger a bit before horizontal scrolling and see if it works.